# What's the best way to use a service in react?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, service-object

Since hooks was introduced in React, React means functional programming. But sometimes a "service"-like object is needed to solve some features. I.e.:

```js
function MyComponente() {
  const cache = useCache({ name: "my-component" });

  console.log(cache.getSelectedItem());
  console.log(cache.setSelectedItem(5));
  // ....

  return <Items cache={cache} />;
}
```

In the above code the "service"-like object is the `cache`. Here the `cache` instance is created with a "hook"-approach. The code could look like the following:

```js
import { cacheRegister, defaultFilters } from "../reactive-vars";

const useCache = ({name}) => {
  const initialState = cacheRegister[name]();
  const currentState = cacheRegister[name];

  return useRef({
    getName: () => name,
    getSelectedItem: () => cacheRegister[name].selectedItem,
    setSelectedItem: (item) => cacheRegister[name]({ ...cacheRegister[name], selectedItem: item }),
    // ....
  });
}
```

Is this the best approach? The `useRef` avoids the recreation of the cache-instance and keeps the reference of cache stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `useRef` definitely. That is the way I am utilizing services on my React projects. As you mentioned, ref is a stable wrapper, and since services should be one-time instantiated and not depending on some outer state, then useRef makes it perfect to use. I just like to define services with JS classes, and then to use it with something like: `const service = useRef(new SomeService(...someParams))`;

Comment: The disadvantage of the approach is, that the param of `useRef` is executed everytime the `useRef`-function is executed. In your case `new SomeService` is called, but the new instance is trashed.

Comment: Yes, but I strictly tend to instantiate service only once(when useRef is initially executed) and then just to reuse same ref value across the component lifecycle.

Comment: But you are instantiating it every time, but only first instance is used.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point - what do you mean by "every time"?

Comment: I mean, that everytime your component, which uses your service with i.e. `useCache`, is rendered your `useRef` is called and therefore the `new SomeService` is executed. We would need a `useLazyRef(() => new SomeService)`. The unnecessary instantiation is annoying, but probably has no impact.

Comment: I got your point now. Well, yes, but if service requires some inputs then instantiation would be required each time we need to use service. But I agree that there are cases when we could have singleton-like services where we can try to avoid unnecessary instantiations, even though I am pretty sure those extra instantiations have no costs in terms of performance.

Comment: I am of your opinion. Thanks for the exchange.